# Setting base HTML font-size in vw to make everything responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have set the base font size of my website like this:

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

Given that most browsers default font size is 16px this results in a font size of 10px. I have then used REM measurements on all elements.

What I would like to do is this:

At a screen size of 1440px I will add a media query breakpoint and make the base HTML font-size responsive – so that all of my site shrinks proportionally. 10px at 1440px results in the following:

```
html {
    font-size: 0.6944444444444vw;
}
```

Then when everything starts to get too small I'll add in another media query breakpoint and do something like:

```
  html {
        font-size: 56.25%; /* 9px */
    }
```

This work brilliantly, but I haven't seen websites using `vw` units on the base HTML font-size. Are there issues with this?

Comment: Setting the font-size in vw units will stop users from zooming the text size. Which is an accessibility fail.

Comment: Lots of people do set font-size in vw units. But yes good point

Comment: I have used html relative sizing for most of my websites and my clients love this!